# Automating SQL script

Tags: sql, shell, unix, vertica

I am new to programming world. I have a SQL script which needs to be automated. The automation required is as follows :

1) Script should run every sunday

2) Automatically dump the results in to DUMP_YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.txt

3) Result set is tar gziped

4) upload to SFTP URL with provided username and password.

I am using :
UNIX,
Vertica DB

Can the Gurus here please help ?

Comment: What did you already try and what was the result?

Comment: For (3) :  for i in `ls *.txt`; do /usr/bin/gzip $i; done 
For (4) : sftp UNAME@IPADDRESS sftp> mput .gz

No luck yet at (1) and (2) , appreciate any pointers you may have to give me directions as i am a rookie - 1st day at programming :)

Comment: This is pretty broad. The short answer is, write a shell script that calls `vsql` to connect and execute sql. Use parameters like `\o` to output sql to a file and `\a` to set unaligned data and `\t` for tuples only. Use `gzip` and/or `tar` and scp or sftp client to send the file. Use `cron` to schedule it.  This isn't hard, but it's a lot of different pieces if you aren't familiar with them. Start simple with getting vsql to create the file, then build a script around it.

Comment: @woot : Got that part covered i guess.

\pset border 0
\pset format unaligned
\pset footer
\pset fieldsep '|'
\C

\o :fname

in the fname : how do i insert the timestamp is the question.

Comment: @woot but did that with (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really 4 questions and should probably asked as such. To answer in the current format though:

**1) Schedule a Task Automatically - Crontab**

In the terminal, type `crontab -e`.

If you want something every Sunday at 1am, add the following line:

```
0 1 * * * 0 /path/to/script/script.sh
```

This will execute the script every Sunday.

**2) Setting the output of the command**

I'm only familiar with oracle. The format is probably similar.  In order to get the filename as you want it, you'd use the date function as follows. (This is how I would do it in with Oracle):

```
d=$(date +%Y%M%D%H%M)
var=$(sqlplus -s / as blahblahblah
select * from stuff;
exit
EOF
)

file_name=DUMP_${d}MISS.txt
echo "${var}" >> ${file_name}
```

Note that your date command is probably different, if you do a man page on date it will tell you which parameters you'd need to get the date formatted as you like.

**3) Taring the output**

```
tar -xvf ${file_name}
```

**4) Send over SFTP**
You'd have to authenticate the sftp, that is beyond the scope of what anyone can answer without more details. Once you have the machines setup to authenticate, you would do:

```
sftp username@server<<EOF
put ${file_name}
EOF
```

Comment: Careful. That cron will execute a lot more than one time every Sunday. You want something more like `0 1 * * 0` to run at a specific time every Sunday.

Comment: Oh yeah duh. I haven't had to every cron off something like this. Normally the day of the week cron is used as a limiting factor, not as the executable factor. (E.g. I've always done this as, run this every day *except* Sunday). Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Sorry it was still not right. I changed it for you. What you had would execute every 1 minute during the 1am hour on Sunday. ;-)

Comment: /facepalm Doesn't look like the OP needed this advice or it didn't work for them judging by the absence of any more input after yesterday AM